# Android Studio is looking at wrong place for SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I had installed Android-SDK at F:/Eclipse/Android-SDK and pointed it as my SDK location when Android studio asked. But later I deleted the Android studio and installed the latest version [1.5.1] also deleted my Android-SDK and installed the new one supplied with Android Studio at F:/IDE/Android-SDK.

But now when-ever I try to run my project it gives error "Build tools 23.0.1 no found in the SDK".

Few things that I already have checked.:

1. Environment variable "ANDROID_HOME" is correctly set to F:/IDE/Android-SDK.
2. Android Studio > File > Project Structure > SDK path are correctly set to F:/IDE/Android-SDK.
3. local.properties file in my project also has the line SDK.dir=F:\IDE\Android-SDK.
4. I can access/update my SDK from SDK manager provided in Android studio properly without any issue it even recognises all the build tools installed [most latest is 23.0.2].
5. When I delete local.properties, Android studio tries to build from F:/Eclipse/Android-SDK (Old path) not from the correct path.
6. When I update build.gradle and change the tools using buildToolsVersion="some_other_version" still results in the same problem, Android Studio cannot find the build tools or may be the SDK. ( versions installed at F:/IDE/Android-SDK are 19.0.0, 21.0.2, 22.0.1, 23.0.1, 23.0.2)

After above steps it's certain that the problem is Android Studio is looking at wrong place when trying to build the project. I tried copying Android-SDK to previous directory and it worked. 
So the question is where else Android Studio checks to find the SDK while building as I already updated the environment variable, SDK path in studio and SDK.properties files?

I have searched a lot, the only thing others try to tell is to update the local.properties file and/or add the correct environment variable.

**project level build.gradle**

```
task clean << {
    println('ignore clean task in root project')
    def bdir = new File('./build')
    if (bdir.exists()) {
       bdir.deleteDir()
    }
}
```

**app level build.graddle**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        project.ext.set("apiCode","")
        project.ext.set("apiCodeNum",0.0F)
        apiCode = ((project.hasProperty('API'))?API:'23.1')
        apiCodeNum = Float.parseFloat(apiCode)
        if (apiCodeNum == 19F) {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+"
        } else if (apiCodeNum == 21.1F) {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+"
        } else if (apiCodeNum >= 21.2F || apiCodeNum <= 22.2F) {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+"
        } else if (apiCodeNum >= 22.3F || apiCodeNum < 23.1F) {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.+"
        } else if (apiCodeNum >= 23.1F){
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+"
        }
        ...
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "XXXX");
star.packageID = 'XXXXX'
star.version.major = 16
star.version.minor = 0
star.version.patch = 14
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.XXX.android.XXX'
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.XXX
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.XXX
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard.flags'
        }
    }
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Open SDK manager in android studio; Check for android studio location;Launch Standalone sdk manager and check the build tool version under tools section

Comment: post both your app level gradle file and project level gradle file

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar thanks for the reply, I have already mentioned in the question that that I can access SDK manager from Android studio. I have check standalone version is also working fine.

Comment: @Apoorv In SDK manager setting of android studio you can relocate your  android SDK directory.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I have set that too, in the sdk manager of Android studio. I can access the correct SDK path from Android studio, I can update it and launch stand alone instance too. The problem is only when I try to build the project, then only it checks at the wrong path (there is no sdk present at F:/eclipse/Android-SDK/ at all). When I delete local.properties files,  it recreates it with correct path too.